# php how to get reference in closure before the object is defined

Tags: php

I have a class, there is a`test` function in class `A`. I want to get a reference of `$server` in `$invoker's` function body. I use `Closure` get a reference of `$this`, but i can't get a reference of `$server` using Closure because `$server` is defined **after** `$inovker` is defined.

Thanks.

```
class A {
    public test() {
        $self = $this;

        $invoker = function () use($self){
            $self.test2(); // ok, no problem, Closure is my best friend
            $server.someMethod(); //Error, How to access $server here?
        }

        $server = new B($invoker);
    }

    public test2(){
        echo "Thank you";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a chicken-egg issue. Since PHP processes from top to bottom this wouldn't work. What you can doe is create a global variable to hold $server. You pass this variable to invoker, but only after class B is called you can use the global variable.
I wouldn't recommend this because you rely on an uninitialized variable. It looks like your trying some C logic in PHP.